# Controlling an industrial servo motor through moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-control, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to control an additional motor along with my UR5 using moveit. I have added new controller to the moveit config controllers.yaml called rail_controller and made necessary changes to the URDF like adding extra joint and transmissions.

```
 controller_list:
  - name: "arm_controller"
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [shoulder_pan_joint, shoulder_lift_joint, elbow_joint, wrist_1_joint, wrist_2_joint, wrist_3_joint]

  - name: "rail_controller"
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - rail_joint
```

As the next step I wrote an action server that can take FollowJointTrajectory type of command. Here's is the file

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include <control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.h>
#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h>

class RobotTrajectoryFollower
{
protected:

  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  actionlib::SimpleActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> as_; 
  std::string action_name_;

public:

  RobotTrajectoryFollower(std::string name) :
    as_(nh_, name, false),
    action_name_(name)
  {
    //Register callback functions:
    as_.registerGoalCallback(boost::bind(&RobotTrajectoryFollower::goalCB, this));
    as_.registerPreemptCallback(boost::bind(&RobotTrajectoryFollower::preemptCB, this));

    as_.start();
  }

  ~RobotTrajectoryFollower(void)//Destructor
  {
  }

  void goalCB()
  {
     ROS_INFO("RAIL CONTROLLER ACTION-GOAL RECEIVED");
    // accept the new goal
    //goal_ = as_.acceptNewGoal()->samples;
  }

  void preemptCB()
  {
    ROS_INFO("%s: Preempted", action_name_.c_str());
    // set the action state to preempted
    as_.setPreempted();
  }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "action_server");

  RobotTrajectoryFollower RobotTrajectoryFollower("/rail_controller/follow_joint_trajectory");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

What should be the next step,so that I can forward the commands received on this server callback from moveit followjointtrajectory client to the actual physical servo motor that I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I seem to have stuck here with so many types of controller documentation,I am unable to find the right resource to follow.

---

Edit: Thanks for the prompt reply.

So, I read about ros_control and modified the [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate) to have my railcontroller configured instead of the rrbot.
The code for my setup is here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3-QK1vsHSXhd3pKcS1VX3lqTUk?usp=sharing

Here's the railrobot_controllers.yaml as defined in ros_control package:

```
# ros_control_boilerplate Settings -----------------------
# Settings for ros_control control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01

# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
   joints:
      - rail_joint

# Publish all joint states ----------------------------------
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
   type:         joint_state_controller/JointStateController
   publish_rate: 50

# Joint Trajectory Controller -------------------------------
# For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller
position_trajectory_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
   # These joints can likely just be copied from the hardware_interface list above
   joints:
      - rail_joint

# Individual Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
# Allows to send individual ROS msg of Float64 to each joint separately
rail_joint_position_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
   joint: joint1
   pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

What I cant seem to figure out how the controller above defined here in ros_control_boilerplate/railrobot_control/config/railrobot_controllers.yaml  ,will communicate with the follow joint trajectory action server that will in turn connect to moveit.

My understanding of ros_control and it's integration with moveit is quite amateur at the moment.I would appreciate if you can help me fill these missing pieces of knowledge.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267868/controlling-an-industrial-servo-motor-through-moveit/) by [Anirudh_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/29491/anirudh_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:
Please don't post answers unless you are actually *answering* your own question. For everything else, use comments or *update* your original question. This is not a regular forum (with multiple posts following each other).

I've merged your answer into your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest to use [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control). It's a bit of a learning curve, but the "only" thing you'd need to do is write a [hardware_interface](http://wiki.ros.org/hardware_interface) that knows how to pass on (fi) position setpoints to your *industrial servo motor* using whatever mechanism (a fieldbus, serial, TCP/IP, UDP, whatever).

After you have that, all the rest (action server, position control, etc) is already done for you.

You then just have to configure a [joint_trajectory_action](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller) controller on top of your `hardware_interface` and that's it.

Now treat that as you do the Action server that your robot driver provides you with, configure MoveIt to use it (just as in your OP) and things should start working.

---

Note that doing things like this -- with separate drivers -- will make *true* synchronous motion execution impossible, as there are too many asynchronous things going on. If you need synchronous execution, you could look into [combined_robot_hw](http://wiki.ros.org/combined_robot_hw).

---

Edit:

> What I cant seem to figure out how the controller above defined here in `ros_control_boilerplate/railrobot_control/config/railrobot_controllers.yaml`, will communicate with the follow joint trajectory action server that will in turn connect to moveit.

You have this in your `railrobot_controllers.yaml`:

```
# Joint Trajectory Controller -------------------------------
# For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller
position_trajectory_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
   # These joints can likely just be copied from the hardware_interface list above
   joints:
      - rail_joint
```

This *is* the joint trajectory action server.

From [wiki/joint_trajectory_controller - Sending trajectories - Available interfaces](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller#Available_interfaces):

> There are two mechanisms for sending trajectories to the controller: by means of the **action interface** or the topic interface.

See also [Section 3.1.1 - Action interface](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller#Action_interface).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirudh_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/29491/anirudh_s/) on 2017-08-03**:
Section 3.1.1 - Action interface ,so asper this,position_trajectory_controller in railrobot_controllers.yaml will start an action server listening on /ns/follow_joint_trajectory ,on which moveit can send commands?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:
I don't really understand what you're asking, but afaict, you just need to configure MoveIt to use the `position_trajectory_controller` action server (which is provided by the `JointTrajectoryController`), and then things should work.

MoveIt is the client, `JointTrajectoryController` is the server.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-03**:
So in total:

- robot driver provides action server for the robot
- rail `hardware_interface` + `JointTrajectoryController` provides action server for the rail
- MoveIt is client of both (configured through `controllers.yaml`)

**Comment by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on 2017-08-15**:
Thanks gvdhoorn ! I am new to ROS and want to write a Hardware Interface. For the link to the Github page you've mentioned, apart from the TCP/IP stuff which all areas of the code need to be worked upon for making the Robot work. For eg. maybe the Main part needs more functions not mentioned there

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-16**:
If you have a question that is not answered in this question already I would suggest you post a new one, not hijack this one.

**Comment by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on 2017-08-30**:
Hello, I had no intentions of doing that. I was able to understand where I was going wrong. Could I please ask you to have a look at my new,
[question](https://answers.ros.org/question/269924/moveit-help-converting-the-world-coordinates-to-joint-coordinates/)

for some inputs.